# Why all result showing failed

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

![I have created Test plans & users for my project, I took 10 number of threads & 2 loops, when i ran the test Result is showing like this .
I have attached two screenshots : 1. Sample result 2. Response data. 
I am not able to understand why result is coming like this
Load time : 0 & latency: 0, then why error count:1 it should be OK.]

[image]
[image]

I am doing a web based project. I am doing performance testing using JMeter.
 I have created 10 users for sample test of my project & have taken 2 loops . I tested for all pages of my project but error or warning is showing in all results.

I have checked for Facebook & Gmail pages also for getting clarity but for Facebook & Gmail it shows error in results.

What to do?
Why error is showing?
somebody help
Thanks in advance

Comment: at least you should post the warning message, or a screenshot

Comment: @HoàngLong I have added two screenshots please check once

Comment: paste the snapshot or request details of landing page. I think issue is there and your screenshot proves it.

Comment: @NachiketKate i have already added screenshots... you have a look

Answer (score 0):

@sonam thats the url exception,check the url path that have you specified correct URL
because it rises the "java.netURI Syntax Exception"

Answer (score 0):

You have most probably misconfigured the HTTP Request by putting the URL in "Server Name of IP" field like this:

[image]

While you should set it like this:

[image]